# Leptonica-1.82.0 not found in .NET runtime

Tags: .net, runtime-error, runtime, tesseract, leptonica

I recently had a huge problem using TESSERACT OCR in my .NET application on Windows 10. I went through several forums and went deep into the WEB and I didn't find anything that would solve this problem. After a lot of testing I managed to solve the problem!

If you are experiencing this, make sure your system has the c++ 2015 - 2022 redistribution.

Download the x86 and x64 versions here:
**https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vc_redist.x86.exe**

**https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vc_redist.x64.exe**

After doing this installation, the problem was fixed. I hope they help you!